# Convert Boolean to integer in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an image in GEE (`image1`) that I am conditionally subtracting from another image (`image2`). If the condition **is** met, I do not want the subtraction to happen (i.e. nothing happens to `image2`). If the condition **is not** met, I do want the subtraction to go ahead.

In a bid to avoid using `ee.Algorithms.If`, which seems to be furtively regarded as terrible ([see here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#avoid-ee.algorithms.if)), my thought was to multiply `image1` by zero if the condition is met, such that the subtraction can go ahead but with no actual effect. I.e. a constant zero image would be subtracted from `image2`.

I can do this if I am able to convert a Boolean `true`/`false` into an integer `0`/`1`. But how can I do that in GEE?

Here is an example illustrating where I am up to so far:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d7c5a150e718907d17d19e74fe6221dc

```
// Centre map
Map.setCenter(57.5864, -20.32, 10);

// Load an image
var elev = ee.Image("CGIAR/SRTM90_V4");

// Create a dummy image to subtract
var dummy = elev.divide(3);

// Create boolean variables
var boolTrue = ee.List(["a"]).contains("a");
var boolFalse = ee.List(["a"]).contains("b");

// If boolean is true, create dummy image of 0
var dummyTrue = dummy.multiply(ee.Image(0)).updateMask(dummy);
// Subtract dummy from image - nothing changes
var elevTrue = elev.subtract(dummyTrue);

// If boolean is false, keep dummy image as is
var dummyFalse = dummy.multiply(ee.Image(1)).updateMask(dummy);
// Subtract dummy from image
var elevFalse = elev.subtract(dummyFalse);

// Map outcomes
var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,"bands":["elevation"],"min":0,"max":900,"gamma":1};
Map.addLayer(elev, imageVisParam,'elevation');
Map.addLayer(elevTrue, imageVisParam,'dummy true');
Map.addLayer(elevFalse, imageVisParam,'dummy false');
```

Comment: One is true and zero is false in most Boolean implementations (presence/absence). If you want 0/1 you'll need to flip the logic.

Comment: This seems somewhat convoluted; where are you really trying to get your boolean from?

Comment: You're right @NoelGorelick it is convoluted. It originates from checking whether a list contains any element from another list. However, I just updated the code at the link with a fix that seems to work - checking whether any element from one list equals any element from another list, flattening & taking the distinct values (either 0, 1, or 0 & 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the prompt from Noel I realised I could fix this by changing the way I tested the condition. In my actual code, the condition to be tested is whether a species has agriculture listed as suitable habitat. In practice, the condition comes down to whether the land cover codes listed as suitable contain any of the land cover codes that correspond to agriculture. Using `list.contains()` returns a boolean value. However, I think I have figured out a (non-elegant) way around this, that returns a numeric:

```
// Condition: does one list contain any element from other list?
var agVals = ee.List(['1401', '1402', '1403']);
var species1 = ee.List(['105','305','104','304']);
var species2 = ee.List(['105','305','1401','304']);

// The lists are land cover codes - coerce to numeric
var agVals = agVals.map(function(i){return(ee.Number.parse(i))});
var species1 = species1.map(function(i){return(ee.Number.parse(i))});
var species2 = species2.map(function(i){return(ee.Number.parse(i))});

// Checking if list contains element returns boolean list
print(agVals.map(function(i){return(species1.contains(i))}));
print(agVals.map(function(i){return(species2.contains(i))}));

// Checking if any element in one list equals any element in another returns numeric list
var sp1Check = (ee.List(agVals
  .map(function(i_1){
    return(species1.map(function(i_2){
      return(ee.Number(i_1).eq(ee.Number(i_2)));
    }));
  }))
  .flatten()
  .distinct());
var sp2Check = (ee.List(agVals
  .map(function(i_1){
    return(species2.map(function(i_3){
      return(ee.Number(i_1).eq(ee.Number(i_3)));
    }));
  }))
  .flatten()
  .distinct());

// If max unique value is 1, then at least one agriculture code is contained 
// in species' list of suitable codes - assign a value of 0 (i.e. do nothing)
var sp1Action = (ee.Number(
  sp1Check
  // Get value of last index (max value)
  .get(sp1Check.size().subtract(1)))
  // Check if max value equals 0
  .eq(0)
  );
var sp2Action = (ee.Number(
  sp2Check
  // Get value of last index (max value)
  .get(sp2Check.size().subtract(1)))
  // Check if max value equals 0
  .eq(0)
  );
// Note the flipped value (true = 0, false = 1)
print(sp1Action);
print(sp2Action);
```

The result for species #1 is 1, which means 'do something' (subtract the image) because agriculture is not suitable for this species. Conversely, the result for species #2 is 0 - 'do nothing' - because agriculture *is* suitable for this species.

**EDIT**

As suggested by Noel, no need for double map. Solution below is quicker & cleaner.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a59668b3647dfebcd2e279cdb4e6f5f1

```
// Check for index of agricultural codes in species list
var sp1Check = (ee.List(agVals
  .map(function(agVal){return(species1.indexOf(agVal))})));
var sp2Check = (ee.List(agVals
  .map(function(agVal){return(species2.indexOf(agVal))})));

// If no elements remain after removing -1 values, agriculture not suitable
// - assign a value of 1 (i.e. do something)
var sp1Action =sp1Check.removeAll(ee.List([-1])).size().eq(0);
var sp2Action =sp2Check.removeAll(ee.List([-1])).size().eq(0);

// Note the flipped value (true = 0, false = 1)
print(sp1Action);
print(sp2Action);
```

Comment: Consider using list.indexOf(element) instead of the double map.  It should be tons faster.